# NotFoundAction.EXCEPTION not throwing an exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following relationship:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    //...

    @EmbeddedId
    private SomeEntityIdentity id;

    @OneToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.EXCEPTION) //This is the important bit
    @JoinColumns({
        //...
    })
    private OtherEntity example;

    //...
}
```

Then, I use Spring data's `findOne()` to grab my entity by the Id:

```
SomeEntityIdentity id = new SomeEntityIdentity();
id.setAttribute1(1);
id.setAttribute2(new BigDecimal(123));
return this.someEntityRepository.findOne(id);
```

The problem is that no exception is thrown if `OtherEntity` is not found, as `findOne()` simply returns null. Even if I set `@OneToOne(optional = false)` I still get a null from `findOne()`, when I was excepting only `OtherEntity` to be null.

I believe an exception should be thrown. Does anyone any have ideas?

Thank you!

---

**Edit:** Identity and Repository classes below.

```
@Embeddable
public class SomeEntityIdentity implements Serializable {
    private int attribute1;
    private BigDecimal attribute2;

    public void setAttribute1(int attribute1) {
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
    }

    public void setAttribute2(BigDecimal attribute2) {
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface SomeEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, SomeEntityIdentity> {
}
```

Comment: Hmm, isn't it working correcly, then? When `findOne()` doesn't return a `SomeEntity` instance, the `@NotFound` annotation is never being processed, anyway. I have to say that I've never used that construct, but that's how I would comprehend your case.

Comment: Are you sure the entity with the given identifier exists? Please post `SomeEntityIdentity`. `@EmbeddedId` suggests the id is composed of more than one property, yet you're only setting one property on `id` before calling `findOne`

Comment: @Matt, `SomeEntity` exists in the database, I've grabbed the SQL from hibernate debug logs and confirmed that a record is returned. The entity that does not exist in the database is `OtherEntity`.

Comment: @crizzis, regarding the identity it was just an example as I can't expose the actual field names. I've updated my question to reflect the actual code I have, with just names changed. I'm 100% positive that the `SomeEntity` record exists, hibernate is doing a left outer join and the query returns a result if I execute it in an SQL client.

Comment: Does fetching `SomeEntity` work when `OtherEntity` exists? Just a wild shot, but could `BigDecimal` be at fault here? Is it possible to use `BigInteger` (or `Long`) for your use case instead? My guess is that `new BigDecimal(123)` is not *really* equal to the db value for some reason

Comment: Try to use `getOne()` instead of `findOne()`. Probably the problem is that `findOne()` returns `Optional.empty()`

Comment: Exception will be thrown only when an otherEntity is not found on a association.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that contributed! It ended up being incompatible versions between Spring and Hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be an incompatibility between Hibernate and Spring Data versions.

This project was using Hibernate `4.3.1.Final` to take advantage of JPA `2.1` features; but with `spring-data-jpa` `1.6.6.RELEASE`, that doesn't support that Hibernate version.

Because everything was working correctly (up until this issue) I didn't notice this at first. When I tried upgrading `spring-data-jpa` to an Hibernate `4.3` compatible version I couldn't, because `spring-data-jpa` jumps from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 5 on `2.0.x` versions. This also seems to require Java 8, so that was a no go for me.

Ended up downgrading to Hibernate `3.6.10.Final` and everything started working OK.

**TL;DR:** Always check version compatibility between Spring and other libraries, even if there's no obvious errors.

I just wanted to finish by saying that Spring version management is a total pain.

---

Working dependency configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error on hibernate '5.4.12.Final'. I've tried downgrading to '3.6.10.Final' like you have but now instead it always throws an exception, regardless of the value I provide for @NotFound